# Qt. Hide QDialog from taskbar, when call it from plugin

Tags: qt, plugins, qdialog

I develop an app with plugins. Each plugin should have it's own settings window (QDialog type).

If plugin's settings form was included in main project, I'll simply create it with passing main form as parent as said here: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#QDialog (and in Google results for this problem).

But when QDialog declared in separated plugin, I think that it's ugly and insecure to pass main form as parent from main app to plugin instance.

Any ideas? Stub QWidget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'd just create stub QWidget as suggest earlier:

```
QWidget *a = new QWidget();
settingsForm = new OpenFolderSettings(a);
...
delete settingsForm;
delete a;
```

So now dialog doesn't show button on taskbar. Also, no new window appear.

Answer (score 1):

I have a small idea. This is different approach but it might work in your case too. As I understand you are trying to create settings manager for you application. You can use `QSettings` for example and store settings for each plugin in different subgroup. For example you have a main app settings and two other plugins.

```
[Main App]
key1=val1
key2=val2

[Plugin1]
key1=val1
key2=val2

[Plugin1]
key1=val1
key2=val2
```

This way you could easily construct a `QDialog` in your main appication and change/save the settings. In turn the main application notifies plugins via signal that settings have changed and need to be reloaded. This way you encapsulate you main application from your plugins.

**update**

Thanks for a quick feedback. The approach I proposed is MainApplication centric but it can be redesigned to be decentralized. Since `QSettings` is application specific your plugins can store their settings in one configuration with main app as before. One modification I would make is the following. You can create a `QDialog` within your plugin and modify the settings without necessity for main app to be aware of this process.

Comment: Each plugin should have it's own settings window. So, if main application will create plugin's own settings windows, it should know about it. I.e. plugins should be included into main project. That is not my case.

Comment: The only problem is taskbar button of settigs window.

Comment: @MaximKorobov Not necessarily. You can interface your app with plugins with traditional signal/slot mechanism to make plugins aware of settings change.

Comment: Who will create new plugin's settings window in your way?

Comment: I see. Yes. Now I understand you. I'd start from this way, but switched to "let plugin control it's own settings" (not save - when user click OK, plugin tell new settings to main window, which save it to XML) approach. Unfortunately, plugins settings could be changed not only text boxes, radio buttons and and check boxes, but via custom editors too. Lets imagine that user could select colors from color boxes. So when main window preparing new settings it should ask plugin about editors types (array of 3 color boxes), their placements on settings form layout, maybe, labels placements and texts.

Comment: This is not limited to these parameters. Also main window - plugin messaging protocol should include custom event metadata. I.E. if user select first color as green, he can't select it in second color box. You see, sounds very heavy and bulky. So I turns to plugin-controllable settings windows.